# Asset file referenced from model instances, how to restrict access to the URL

Tags: django, authorization, assets, access-control

How can I serve asset files each from a cacheable URL, and also check access permission on the corresponding Django model instance before allowing a request to that URL?

I have a Django application where model instances often have corresponding “asset” files, for example an image for an icon or a photo of the product.

These assets should be served from a URL that is predictable and cacheable.

Some of these assets are public and can be viewed without special authorisation. Others are not, and the URL should return an error response (such as [HTTP 401 “Unauthorized”](https://http.cat/401) or [HTTP 404 “Not Found”](https://http.cat/404)). The distinction is determined by the Django app view permissions for the corresponding model.

It seems neither the Django “staticfiles” app nor the “ImageField” processing allows for this in a way I can see.

What should I be using to **connect access to an asset file URL to Django model authorisation and permissions**?